# Expected minimum absolute difference to a given point?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to compute the expected absolute difference between $n$ iid uniformly between $[- \epsilon, \epsilon]$ sampled points to a given point $- \epsilon< c < \epsilon$:

$$
\mathrm{E}(\mathrm{min}(|x_1-c|,|x_2-c|,...,|x_n-c|))
$$

I know, that the expected minimum of n iid uniformly between $[0, \epsilon]$ sampled points is $\frac{\epsilon}{n+1}$.

How would I go about this problem though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\min|X_i - c|$ is non-negative and you want to compute its expectation, we can compute its survival function first. Consider the survival function of individual $|X_i - c|$:

$$ \begin{align}
S(x)&=\Pr\{|X_i - c| > x\}  \\
&= \Pr\{X_i > c + x\} + \Pr\{X_i < c - x\} \\
&= \begin{cases}
1 & \text {if} & x \leq 0 \\
\displaystyle 1 - \frac {x} {\epsilon} & \text{if} & 0 < x \leq \epsilon - |c|\\
\displaystyle \frac {\epsilon + |c| - x} {2\epsilon} & \text {if} & \epsilon - |c| < x < \epsilon + |c| \\
0 & \text{if} & x \geq \epsilon + |c|
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Then the survival function of $\min |X_i - c|$ will be $S(x)^n$ and thus
$$ \begin{align}
 E[\min|X_i - c|] 
&= \int_0^{+\infty}S(x)^ndx \\
&= \int_0^{\epsilon - |c|} \left(1 - \frac {x} {\epsilon} \right)^n dx
+ \int_{\epsilon - |c|}^{\epsilon + |c|} \left(\frac {\epsilon + |c| - x} {2\epsilon} \right)^n dx  \\
&= \left. \frac {-\epsilon} {n+1}\left(1 - \frac {x} {\epsilon} \right)^{n+1} \right|_0^{\epsilon - |c|} + \left.\frac {-2\epsilon} {n+1} \left(\frac {\epsilon + |c| - x} {2\epsilon} \right)^{n+1} \right|_{\epsilon - |c|}^{\epsilon + |c|} \\
&= \frac {\epsilon} {n+1}\left(1 - \frac {|c|^{n+1}} {\epsilon^{n+1}} + 2\frac {|c|^{n+1}} {\epsilon^{n+1}}\right) \\
&= \frac {\epsilon} {n+1}\left(1 + \frac {|c|^{n+1}} {\epsilon^{n+1}} \right)
\end{align}$$

As you see, the answer is minimized when $c = 0$ and it reduced back to the previous solution.